# In linux, all kernel processes share the same kernel stack, each user process has its own stack, correct?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Furthermore, if a user process link a shared lib, say, glib, libX, libY, libZ, then glib and libX, Y, Z have their individual vma structs for text, data, but still share the same stack w/ the user process, correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect.

There's one kernel address space, and no kernel processes.
There are kernel threads, and there are user space threads that enter the kernel. These run in the kernel address space.
Each of these has a separate stack, within the kernel address space.